# Deserialization not filling my variables/response.data shows null

Tags: c#, restsharp

I want to put the jsonBody I get from the Rest API into this class construction.

```
Console.WriteLine(response.Data);
```

Somehow it only returns null.

This my whole code:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("https://euterpe.webuntis.com/WebUntis/jsonrpc.do?school=HTL-Perg");

public void login()
{
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/jason");

    request.AddJsonBody(new
            {
                id = "ID",
                method = "authenticate",
                @params = new 
                {
                    user = "kung",
                    password = "foo",
                    client = "CLIENT"
                },
                jsonrpc = "2.0"
            });

    var response = this.client.Execute<AuthenticationResponse>(request);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Data);
}
```

The request is working and I get the following return of the Rest API:

```
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "id":"ID",
    "result": {
                 "sessionId":"A173BECFB75F66123D6B678BE9745A29",
                 "personType":5, 
                 "personId":1234,
                 "klasseId":123
              }
}
```

Finally this are the two classes the response should get stored to, but the variables seem to stay empty:

```
    public class AuthenticationResponse
    {
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "jsonrpc")]
        public String Jsonrpc { get; set; }
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "id")]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "result", Content=true)]
        AuthenticationResult res { get; set; }
    }

    public class AuthenticationResult
    {
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "sessionId")]
        string sessionId { get; set; }
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "personType")]
        int personType { get; set; }
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "personId")]
        int personId { get; set; }
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "klasseId")]
        int klasseId { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks for every advice.

Comment: Have you tried matching `"jsonrpc","id,"result"` with the `AuthenticationResponse` object? They don't seem to match the json variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AuthenticationResponse possibly needs to be

```
public class AuthenticationResponse
    {
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "result")]
        AuthenticationResult res { get; set; }

        public string jsonrpc { get; set; } // Can remove if you dont need it.
    }
```

**Update**
Based on your comment that this didn't work, please try to use Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize your result.

```
var response = client.Execute(request);
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthenticationResponse>(response.Content);
```

You would have to use JsonPropertyAttribute instead of DeserliazeAs in your class definition.

```
public class AuthenticationResponse
{
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("result")]
        AuthenticationResult res { get; set; }
}

public class AuthenticationResult
{
        [JsonProperty("sessionId")]
        string sessionId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("personType")]
        int personType { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("personId")]
        int personId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("klasseId")]
        int klasseId { get; set; }
}
```

**Additional Option**

You could also use [RestSharp.Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp.Newtonsoft.Json) which makes Newtonsoft.Json default serializer for RestSharp (and skipping the intermediate step).

Comment: @Fobba199l I have made an update in my answer. Could you please try it ? Wondering if the issue has to more to do with default serializer used y RestSharp

Comment: Tried your new suggestion ... it seams like he can't convert string returned by my request into int i need for my class

Is there a way to tell Newtonsoft.Json to convert string to int?

Comment: @Fobba199l Just realized that your "id" is no longer int ( was it int in OP ? ), I have updated the Answer to make it string. It should work now. Please check.

Comment: yea just got that as well :D

Comment: changed DezerialiseAs to JsonProperty

now its working thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have taken a look at your code and tried it with *WebUntis*. Here is a working example as a console app. Especially important is the call to *client.AddHandler* Hope it helps solving your problem.

```
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Deserializers;
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static RestClient client = new RestClient("https://euterpe.webuntis.com/WebUntis/jsonrpc.do?school=HTL-Perg");

        public class AuthenticationResponse
        {
            [DeserializeAs(Name = "id")]
            public string id { get; set; }
            [DeserializeAs(Name = "result", Content = true)]
            public AuthenticationResult result { get; set; }
        }

        public class AuthenticationResult
        {
            [DeserializeAs(Name = "sessionId")]
            public string sessionId { get; set; }
            [DeserializeAs(Name = "personType")]
            public int personType { get; set; }
            [DeserializeAs(Name = "personId")]
            public int personId { get; set; }
            [DeserializeAs(Name = "klasseId")]
            public int klasseId { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            client.AddHandler(new JsonDeserializer(), "application/json-rpc");

            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            request.AddJsonBody(new
            {
                id = "ID",
                method = "authenticate",
                @params = new
                {
                    user = "kung",
                    password = "foo",
                    client = "CLIENT"
                },
                jsonrpc = "2.0"
            });

            var response = client.Execute<AuthenticationResponse>(request);
            var resp = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.RawBytes, 0, (int)response.ContentLength);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Data);
        }
    }
}
```

Greetings,
Rainer.

Answer (score 0):

In your Json there is nothing called "res" that is being returned .
This should fix your issue :

```
public class AuthenticationResponse
    {
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "jsonrpc")]
        public String Jsonrpc {get;set;}
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "result")]
        AuthenticationResult Result { get; set; }
    }
```